# iOs pushnotification using FCM

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I am using FCM to trigger PushNotification for iOS devices, as per iOS documentation for offline iOS devices.

"Apple Push Notification service includes a Quality of Service (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts to deliver a notification and the destination device is offline, APNs stores the notification for a limited period of time and delivers it when the device becomes available again. This component stores only the most recent notification per device and per app. If a device is offline, sending a notification request targeting that device causes the previous request to be discarded. If a device remains offline for a long time, all its stored notifications in APNs are discarded."

So if the app user has two notification which got generated during the offline period, only the latest message will be delivered to the user iOS device.

My question is, how the messenger app's like Whatsapp, facebook are pushing all the messages that are generated even if the device is offline for a long period of time say (1 hour) to iOS devices ?